# Is there a way to replicate JPARepository methods for same structure tables?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, repository

Bit of context : I am using five tables with same structure, as follows :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Book {

    @Column(name = "BOOK_ID")
    private String bookId;

    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private String customerId;

    @Column(name = "AUTHOR")
    private String author;

    @Column(name = "YEAR")
    private Integer year;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

}
```

Then all five tables look like this :

```
@Data
@Entity

@Table(name = "FANTASTIC_BOOK")
public class FantasticBook extends Book {
}
```

I would like to get the correct bookId regarding the table it is in. The 5 tables are mandatory. 
My repository looks like this :

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer> {

    List<? extends Book> findByBookId(String bookId);

}
```

I thought the wildcard would help by saying to Jpa "hey, the request comes from Fantastic / Horror Book so you should use the method in their respective table". 
But it's not. If I run this, the result is :

```
[FantasticBook(), FantasticBook(), FantasticBook(), FantasticBook(), FantasticBook(), HorrorBook(), HorrorBook(), HorrorBook(), HorrorBook(), HorrorBook()]
```

But my call looks like this :

```
MedievalBookList = (List<MedievalBook>) BookRepository.findByBookId(bookId);
```

My interpretation here is that, I have this "BookId" in all 5 tables to test Data. It means that, with the wildcard, it actually looks in every child of the Book.class , which is something I don't want. 
Is there a way to bypass this ?

Also, a solution I had was to make the repo like this :

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer> {

    List<MedivalBook> findByBookId(String bookId);

}
```

But if I do this, I can't make the 5 same queries.

Any of you got a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the way how JPA Inheritance works.

If you query for a Book you get all Books incl. the Subclasses and if you query for MedivalBook you only get the MedivalBooks.

On solution could be to use a custom query like:

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE TYPE(b) = :type and b.bookId = :bookId")
    List<Book> findByBookId(Class type, String bookId);

}
```

The call would then be:

```
findByBookId(MedivalBook.class, "The ID");
```

Comment: I guess you mean custom query and not a customer query :)

Comment: @M.Deinum Exactly :-) Thanks. Btw. do you know if TYPE would work in the method signature? I will go and try

Comment: I'm probably missing something ; I don't understand how I can tell this query / pass the parameter that will make the query understand I want a fantastic book over a medieval one.
Could you show me the call I have to do, so I'm sure I understand ?

Comment: I added the call

Comment: Your solution looks like it works but implemented in my code, it gave me a IndexOutOfBoundsException . I'm trying to figure it out, then come back to you.
Anyway, thanks for your help !

Comment: @SimonMartinelli , the solution was to add the wildcard.
List<Book> customFindByBookId(String bookId, Class<?> type);
Thank you for your help, have a nice day !

Comment: I'm happy to help